# python incorrectly values < and >

Tags: python, floating-point

The following is my code that calculates <, > incorrectly. About 3X into giving raw_input it will do things like value 12 < 4. I have added several float commands to try to keep it from having problems with string and int. I'm very new to coding.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        float(num)
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input" 
        break
    float(num)
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
        float(largest)
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
        float(largest)
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
        float(largest)
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num
        float(smallest)
    print num

print "Maximum", largest
print "Minimum", smallest
```

Comment: What does "do things like value 12 < 4" mean?

Comment: you're not comparing `12 <  4`; you're comparing `"12" < "4"`

Comment: Also, just saying `float(smallest)` doesn't change `smallest`.  You need to do `smallest = float(smallest)`.

Comment: @zondo is correct. In your case, if you just modify the try block to `try: num = float(num)` then i dont think you will have to make any other changes. Just that you can remove all the float() calls.

Answer (score 1):

`float(num)` computes the floating-point value of `num`, but doesn't *do* anything with it; in particular, it doesn't change the value of `num`.  You'll need an assignment to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, after casting `num` as a `float`, you never actually *assign* it to anything.

```
float(num)
```

Instead you will want to re-assign `num` *after* the conversion

```
num = float(num)
```

If you don't do this (as in your current code), when you're performing the comparisons, you're doing a *string* comparison rather than a numeric comparison.

```
"12" < "4"   # True
```

Comment: I think you need to remove that initial conversion to float in order to remove the downvote on your answer, since the user is using the input given to a string "done". Just my wildest guess though!

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yup! Just realized that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Cyr1lfiggus If Suever answerd your question, please mark their answer as accepted (green check).

Answer (score 1):

`float` does not change the variable in-place - it returns a cast value, which you are ignoring by not saving it anywhere. Just assign it, and you should be OK:

```
try:
    num = float(num)
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid input" 
    break

if largest is None:
    largest = num
if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
if num > largest:
    largest = num
if num < smallest:
    smallest = num
print num
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the value in num in your code. Typing "float(num)" doesn't really do anything because it's just temporarily casting that variable as a floating point number. To actually change the value I suggest the following edits.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        float(num)
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid input" 
        break
    num = float(num)
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    print num

print "Maximum", largest
print "Minimum", smallest
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick feedback!!